# Implement algolia search like Producthunt.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I was looking at Producthunt.com and noticed that it was updating query param as you type. I know they're using algolia search but I was wondering how they update the query param. I was looking at https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails-example/ but instantsearch in the example doesn't seem to update the uri param as you type.

has anyone been able to implement something like it with algoliasearch-rails gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be interested in https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/?

Comment: I looked at instantsearch.js but I kept getting `Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings` when I typed in a query. I also looked at this issue, https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/731 but didn't really solve it.

Comment: Can you share with me the website where I can see the error? Would be easier to debug

Comment: well turns out I was missing a <div> tag. haha